# Count the number of subarrays where the selected element is the largest value

Tags: python, algorithm, math

We have an array of integers `X`. The task is to return an array `Y` of the same size, where the `ith` element in `Y` is the count of the subarrays having the `ith` element in `X` as maximum.

For example:

```
X: [8, 7, 1, 12, 11, 4, 10, 2, 3, 6, 9]
Y: [3, 2, 1, 32, 7, 1, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is my solution with quadratic time complexity.

```py
def solve(A):

    def expand(i):
        left, right = i, i
        while left > 0 and A[i] >= A[left - 1]:
            left -= 1

        while right < len(A) - 1 and A[i] >= A[right + 1]:
            right += 1

        length = right - left + 1
        mid = i - left
        return (mid + 1) * (length - mid)

    result = [0] * len(A)
    MOD = 10**9 + 7
    for i in range(len(A)):
        count = expand(i)
        count %= MOD
        result[i] = count

    return result
```

The idea is that we go left and right using two pointers while the elements are greater than our current element. Once we have the array where the current element is max, we can get the number of subarrays by `(start_index) * (end_index - start_index + 1)`

The algorithm has to run on very large test cases. How do I reduce the time complexity to atleast `NlogN`?

Comment: Are the X values all different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one `O(n)` version. The one comment in the code should make the idea pretty clear.

JavaScript code:

```js
// Preprocess previous higher and lower elements in O(n)
// Adapted from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element
function prev(A, higherOrLower) {
  function compare(a, b){
    if (higherOrLower == 'higher')
      return a < b
    else if (higherOrLower == 'lower')
      return a > b
  }
  
  let result = new Array(A.length)
  let stack = [A.length - 1]

  for (let i=A.length-2; i>=0; i--){ 
    if (!stack.length){ 
      stack.push(A[i])
      continue
    }

    while (stack.length && compare(A[ stack[stack.length-1] ], A[i]))
      result[ stack.pop() ] = i

    stack.push(i)
  }

  while (stack.length)
    result[ stack.pop() ] = -1

  return result
}

function f(A){
  let prevHigher = prev(A, 'higher')
  let nextHigher = prev(
    A.slice().reverse(), 'higher')
    .map(x => A.length - x - 1)
    .reverse()
  let result = new Array(A.length)
  
  for (let i=0; i<A.length; i++)
    result[i] =
      (i - prevHigher[i]) * (nextHigher[i] - i)
              
  return result
}

var A = [8, 7, 1, 12, 11, 4, 10, 2, 3, 6, 9]

console.log(JSON.stringify(A))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a segment tree for maximums. Then, for each element you will be able to binary search first element, that is greater to the right and to the left. Subarray between these greater elements is the maximum subarray, where the selected element is maximum. Time complexity is O(*N log<sup>2</sup> N*)

Answer (score 0):

That can be done sorting the integer indices based on their rank, considering integer are all different.

Starting from the lower element, we know they should have 1 as value.

Then we feed an array of linked intervals: if a greater element as no linked interval around it, its value is 1 (as the next greater elements surround it).

If we have linked intervals, we take them into account for the subarray count and we update the end (for previous interval) and start (for next interval) so that the global interval is linked around the newly considered integer.

```
# Class to track of already used intervals
class Link:
    def __init__( self, start, end ):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __str__( self ):
         return str( self.start ) + "/" + str( self.end )

# Input
X = [8, 7, 1, 12, 11, 4, 10, 2, 3, 6, 9]

l = len(X)

# Prepare the output
Y = [0] * l

# Prepare link table
links = [None] * l

# Map the integers sorted ranks
for i in sorted( range(l), key = lambda i: X[i] ):
    # See if links are availables around current index
    link_previous = links[i - 1] if i > 0 else None
    link_next = links[i + 1] if i < (l - 1) else None

    # Calculate start/end positions
    start = link_previous.start if link_previous else i
    end = link_next.end if link_next else i

    # Define the current link interval
    links[i] = Link( start, end )

    # Report end at the previous linked interval
    if link_previous:
        links[link_previous.start].end = end

    # Report start at the next linked interval
    if link_next:
        links[link_next.end].start = start

    # Calculate subarray count
    Y[i] = (1 + i - start) * (1 + end - i)

    print( [str(l) for l in links] )
    print( "Y", Y )


print( "Y [3, 2, 1, 32, 7, 1, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4]" )
```

Should be nLog(n) for the sort and n after that.

Note: if integers are not all different, I think adding another start/end (+corresponding value, so that we have current and overall interval) should work. But I don't know what is expected as subarray count in this case.